# how to find the index of an element in a list by giving only a specific part of that element in a list in python

Tags: python

```
a=["cat on the wall" ,"dog on the table","tea in the cup"]
b= "dog"
for i in a:
  if b in i:
    print(a.index(i))
```

The output prints the index of the element where is "dog" is present

can this be done in using any inbuilt function, variable b contains only a part of the element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
a=["cat on the wall" ,"dog on the table","tea in the cup"]
b= "dog"
for idx, v in enumerate(a):
    if b in v:
        print(idx) #-->1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=["cat on the wall" ,"dog on the table","tea in the cup"]
b= "dog"

for z in a:
    if b in z:
        print(a.index(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct way to do it. Other functions (eg. `sorted`) accept a key that they use to compare elements. But `index` depends on equality. So, you have two choices

- override the equality operator. not a good idea in your case, since you have simple strings.
- rewrite you loop, using a regular expression

```py
import re

for word in a:
    position = re.search(b, word)

    if position is not None:
        start_index = position.span()[0]
        print(start_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

As blue_note mentioned there is no direct way for this. You can simplify using [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Like,

```py
a = ["cat on the wall", "dog on the table", "tea in the cup"]
b = "dog"
print ([idx for idx, itm in enumerate(a) if b in itm])
```